# How to convert "01 02:52:12" into a time stamp in Excel and convert it from UTC to PST?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Assuming the month is June and year is 2021, how can you convert "01 02:52:12" into "06/01/21 02:52:12 AM" in excel?
Then convert from UTC to PST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use DATE and TIME:

```
=DATE(2021,6,--LEFT(A1,2))+MID(A1,4,8)-TIME(7,0,0)
```

[image]

Comment: =DATE(2021,6,--LEFT(A1,2))+MID(A1,4,11)-TIME(7,0,0). Modified it to this and it worked! Thank you :)

Comment: What about `=("2021/6/"&A1)-TIME(7,,)`. I'm unsure if it would work in en-US, but it worked for me on a Dutch version of Excel.

Comment: @JvdV yes that would work.  I went with the assumption that the OP would have the month and year is two separate cells and in my mind it was easier to understand than the concatenation of three cells.

Comment: Start time: 31 16:59:17; End time: 02 19:34:56 - But here start time is month of July and end time is August. How would i update the formula?

Comment: You would change the 6 to 8 for the end time.

Comment: Yes that is the quick fix, but if the data size is big, is there a way that i can change the formula to first check if the start date is 7/31 then end date would be calculated as 8/02?

Comment: that is a different question than the one posed here.  New questions get new posts with the needed background data and post.