# Getting DATEVALUE from Dates in mmm-YY format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with many columns for each month in the project timeline and each header is in mmm-YY format (like May-20 for 5/1/2020). I'd like to add some more features that act on date values, but when I use DATEVALUE on a cell that has a value of 'May-20', it calculates to "5/20/2021". I believe I have the cell format for the headers correctly set to Number>Date>Mon-Year style, so I'm not sure why excel is misinterpreting the header values.

Is there a way I can get excel to recognize that "May-20" means 05/01/2020?

Comment: The cell format is ignored by `DATEVALUE`. You don't need it either if the cell truly contains a formatted date and not pure text (that is, you entered something like "2020-05-01" and then formatted it as `MMM-YY`) -- what does `TEXT([cell], "MM-dd-yyyy")` yield?

Comment: @JeroenMostert - OP has text, otherwise `DATEVALUE` would throw an error.

Comment: Are the **headers** in an Excel **table**?

Comment: What about `=--("1-"&A1)` where `A1` is the cell with the "May-20" value.

Comment: Yeah, reading this question made me think about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68999976/9758194) @ScottCraner

Comment: @JvdV I answer too many questions here.  I cannot remember one day to the next sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
=--("1-"&A1)
```

Where your text is in A1.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Can you explain a little as to what the formula is doing?

Comment: It creates a string that excel can interpret as a date, in this case: `1-May-20`.  The `--` is just a short cut to changing text into numbers.  It is the same as `-1*-1*`

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you give me a link or search term to learn more about these 'shortcuts'? I don't think I can google "--"

Comment: These are learned through asking questions and just trying things.  I am self taught and mainly from lurking here.  I do not have any resources outside of Stack Overflow itself.

Comment: @GaryZ - [double unary](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary).

Answer (score -1):

You can format the cells as Custom Format --> `mmm-yy` It will appear as May-20 in the cell, but will have the value 5/20/20 (I'm assuming the day doesn't matter here).

This will however mess up your existing dates. If you need to get them to the proper values you can use this:

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim mth As String
    Dim yr As String
    With ActiveSheet 'Use a real sheet name
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'I used column B here
        For i = 1 To lr
            mth = Split(.Cells(i, 2).Value, "-")(0) 'I used column B here
            yr = Split(.Cells(i, 2).Value, "-")(1)'I used column B here
            Cells(i, 2).Value = DateValue("01 " & mth & " " & yr) 'I used column B here
        Next i
    End With
```

You may want to test it first by not modifying in place.